# Taking a screenshot in robocorp browser timeout error

Tags: python, robotframework

it's my first time using robocorp so I don't understand what these errors mean...
Please help me understand what is causing this error when I try to take a screeenshot using the browser library from robocorp.

Error: locator.screenshot: Timeout 59979.081999999995ms exceeded.
Call log:

- taking element screenshot
- waiting for element to be visible and stable
- element is visible and stable

I don't know why is the screenshot taking so long...

I tried waiting until network is idle but it didn't work:

```
from Browser import Browser

#Configure new browser
browser = Browser()
browser.new_browser(headless=False)
browser.set_browser_timeout(60)

browser.new_page("confidential page from the company...")

browser.wait_until_network_is_idle(10)
try:
  browser.take_screenshot(path_screenshot)            
except Exception as err:
  print("Screenshot timed out before iframe\n")
```

I can´t show much due to confidential company policies but any help understanding **how take_screenshot works** is apreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, I found out that the `browser.take_screenshot(path_screenshot)`
works similar to a camera, it has to "focus" on the website, and it can mess up frequently during that process, resulting in an exception. To solve it, I retried retaking a screenshot, up to 3 times. In all my tests, the maximum amount of retries never exceeded two. If you find this problem and want to be on the safe side, try it up to 4 times, and it will work.